# Create a block view which shows a single item based on offset

Tags: views

I would like to create a block view which shows a single item based on offset. Let me explain ...

I can easily create a block view that shows the title's of the three most recently created nodes. But I want to break this ONE block into THREE blocks, that each show a single item:

- Block A shows the **most recently** created node's title.
- Block B shows the **second most recently** created node's title.
- Block C shows the **third most recently** created node's title.
- All three blocks 'look' have the same layout, etc.

I thought I could do this with a default `display`, and then have 2 or 3 different `display`s. But I cannot seem to alter the `offset` of a display.

Is there a way for me to achieve this, without having to create three seperate views?

**Edit:** By offset, I am referring to the **PAGER** settings of the view.

Comment: What do you mean by "offset"?

Comment: @betherwisser You are genius. By making me look at where `offset` is defined, I realised that I can apply the pager settings to the current display, and not necessarily the entire view.

Comment: Glad I could help.